# PropertyInfo.SetValue for an array is not working

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using .Net 2013, Windows7. I'm able to set and get individual values using reflection. When I try to use reflection to set a value in an array I'm unable to do so. Using reflection I'm able to get the values in an array.

I found what appears to be a workaround for setting the value in an array but I don't understand why the SetValue function doesn't work. Below is my code.

```
            property = type.GetProperty("propDeviceMessageMask", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (property != null)
            {
                DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types[] value = (DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types[])property.GetValue(device, null);

                value[0] = DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled;
                value[1] = DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled;
                value[2] = DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled;
                value[3] = DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled;

                property.SetValue(device, DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled, new object[] { (int)4 });
            }
```

propDeviceMessageMask is an array of 8 DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types. I'm able to get the entire array with the GetValue function. I'm able to edit the values using indexes 0-3. When I try to update index 4 with the SetValue function I get a Parameter Count Mismatch in a TargetParameterCountException.

Comment: As an aside there is no such thing as .Net 2013. There is a Visual Studio version 2013, but that doesn't help us answer your question because that is an editor which has nothing directly to do with the end product. Which version of .Net are you targeting would be a better tag to include with C#.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the number of parameters in index does not match the number of parameters the indexed property takes. So in your case the number is 4, but the array does not have this index. Try this and it shall work:

```
// valid indexes are 0, 1, 2 and 3
property.SetValue(device, DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled, new object[] { (int)3 });
```

More details about how to use the `SetValue` method and how to interpret thrown exceptions at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First off, understand that [arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) are a fixed size in .NET. If it's true that your `propDeviceMessageMask` array initially has 8 items, you should be able to set the value at indexes 0 through 7 just fine using the same syntax you're using for indexes 0 through 3:

```
 value[4] = DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types.Disabled;
```

However, if your array initially only has 4 items, so you can set those values at indexes 0 through 3, but you can't set a value at index 4 (the fifth item). If you need to store 5 items, you'd have to allocate a new array of 5 items, and copy the first 4 values into the new array. Then you can assign that new array to the property.

Alternatively, if you can modify the original class, you should probably use a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), which handles dynamically adding / removing items much more gracefully than an array.

Secondly, it sounds like you have a property defined like this:

```
public DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types[] propDeviceMessageMask { get; set; }
```

It's important to realize that this is *very* different from an indexer property (even though the syntax is similar in some ways), which would look like this:

```
public DEVICE_MESSAGE_MASK_Types this[int index] { ... }
```

The `index` parameters in the `GetValue` / `SetValue` methods can only be used with this latter kind of property. So to set the value of this modified array back to your original object, you'd have to leave the `index` parameter null:

```
property.SetValue(device, value, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between a property and an indexer property.

Answer (score 0):

A property with array type is not the same as an indexed property, although the "usual" source code for both looks like

```
obj.prop[index]
```

The difference matters a great deal when doing reflection.